# NgbDatepicker show months and years only

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am developing an app using Bootstrap 4 components, powered by Angular 4, and i have trouble configuring the NgbDatepicker directive to show only the months and years, not the days - like for credit cards.

I want to select only the month and year, i don't care about choosing a specific day.

My input looks like this:

```
<input id="demodate" type="text" name="demodate" ngbDatepicker
#startDateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="modelDate"/>
```

I tried all the properties listed for the directive listed here

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker

but none of  them seem to help me. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Well there is no native support for that, but you can help yourself with css and `navigate` event. It is not super-nice, but it is functional.

`<ngb-datepicker (navigate)="dateNavigate($event)" 
[showWeekdays]="false" class="datepicker-only-month-select"></ngb-datepicker>`

In your component you can catch the navigate event, which contains previous and new value:

`dateNavigate($event: NgbDatepickerNavigateEvent) {
    console.log($event.next.month);
    console.log($event.next.year);
    ...
    // old value is contained in $event.current
  }`

And finally in global scope CSS, you can hide the day calendar (and add more required styling):

`.datepicker-only-month-select {
  border: 0 !important;
  .ngb-dp-months {
    display: none !important;
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

There is a request for that:

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1811

As of now (Feb/2020), this is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

The existing implementation of https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker doesn't support choosing months + years - it is a date picker.

You might try opening a feature request in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues